# CSS - Change mutltiple things on hover

Tags: html, css

i am new in CSS and i just try to make some "breaking news" or something like that with changing background color when user go with mouse on it, also trying to add some new staff.

How it should look:
[image: example]

My try looks: 
[image: example]

Important thing is that i need to change in same time

1. Background,
2. Add that blue arrow
3. Text color
4. Buble icon on right site

And i have totaly no idea how to do it :(

HTML:

```
  <span id="right">
    <ul>
    <li><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span></li>
    <li><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span></li>
    <li><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span></li>
    <li><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span></li>
    <li><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span></li>
    </ul>
  </span>
```

CSS:

```
#news #right ul li{
    list-style-position: inside;    /* Bodka v novom riadku vo vnutry */
    list-style-type: none;          /* bez bodky */ 
    background-image: url("images/black_bar.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #898989;
    height:45px;
    width: 569px;
    line-height: 45px;
    border 1px;
    border-color: #898989;
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}
#news #right ul li :hover{
    list-style-position: inside;    /* Bodka v novom riadku vo vnutry */
    list-style-type: none;          /* bez bodky */ 
    background-image: url("images/blue_bar.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #898989;
    height:45px;
    width: 569px;
    line-height: 45px;
    border 1px;
    border-color: #898989;
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}  
#news #right ul li a:visited{
    color: #898989;
}
#news #right ul li a:active{
    color: #898989;
}
#news #right ul li a:link{
    color: #898989;
}
#news #right ul{
    padding 0px auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.newsheading{
    background-image: url("images/cs_icon.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;   
}
```

Is here somebody who can help me to fix it?
Live preview can be fine here: http://funedit.com/andurit/try2/

Thanks you all for reading this post.

Comment: Meh.. not to do so much, you can just position the elements like `position:relative; bottom:Xpx`. And you can create arrows with border and padding trick in CSS.

Comment: Right the blue arrow should just display on hover, and shouldnt at any other time, same with other things, i afraid its not just about position, position will just move things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `#news #right ul li :hover{` to `#news #right ul li:hover{` so the style applies to the right element.

Comment: You also forgot to change color property in "#news #right ul li:hover{"

Comment: Thanks man i didnt noticed that, + on your asnwer, anyway can u help me with changing other staff? Like adding that blue arrow and so on?

Comment: You can add them to the html like this:

<li><span class="arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="ballon">10</span></li>

Have them set display:none and show them when hovering using a css rule like this:

Change #news #right ul li:hover .balloon{

Comment: I dont like to add images which are part of web via HTML, there should be just things as images from news and so on

Comment: I published my previous comment before finishing it (pushed enter to insert a new line but published instead). Check it!

Comment: Is there a chance you can write full code for me? I am a bit lost :)

Comment: <li><span class="arrow"></span><span class="newsheading"><a href="#">Gamesites má nový web ou jeeee!</a></span><span class="balloon">10</span></li>

#news #right ul li .balloon{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("images/blue_bar.png");
    display: none;
}

#news #right ul li:hover .balloon{
    
    display: block;
}

Comment: Change width and height and the balloon image in the CSS!

Comment: I have to change few simple things but it actualy working and help me a lot, THANKS MAN!

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue seems to be the `margin-top: 10px;` on the newsheading class I'm not sure where else that is being used but try getting rid of it.

Also try changing `#news #right ul li :hover` to `#news #right ul li span:hover` so that the text isn't affected by the hover.

```
#news #right ul li span:hover{
    list-style-position: inside;    /* Bodka v novom riadku vo vnutry */
    list-style-type: none;          /* bez bodky */ 
    background-image: url("images/blue_bar.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #898989;
    height:45px;
    width: 569px;
    line-height: 45px;
    border 1px;
    border-color: #898989;
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}
```

For a triangle/arrow  try using this technique http://cssarrowplease.com/ or this one http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Good Luck

Comment: Hello man, thanks for your answer. about that arrow i prefer to use it as image not with CSS3 :) is there some other way?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would display an image on hover with css. 
You could keep an image of the arrow there hid it with `disply:none` and show it on hover, or use jQuery http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

I can give something to you about arrow displaying.

```
<div id="the1">
 <div id="the2">
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#the2 {display:none}
#the1:hover #the2 {display:inline}
```

This is hove you can actually show and not show some elements in CSS. You need to carefull #the2 is inside #the1. `#the1:hover #the2` basicly says if you hover #the1, i'll modify #the2.

Hope helps.